# Problem with floating point number in C and Python

Tags: python, c, floating-point

I was doing some question in C and I was asked to provide the output of this question :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a =0.7;
    if(a<0.7)
    {
        printf("Yes");
    }
    else{
        printf("No");
    }
}
```

By just looking at the problem I thought the answer would be *NO* but after running I found that it was *YES*
I searched the web about float and found [0.30000000000000004.com](https://0.30000000000000004.com/)

Just out of curiosity I ran the same code in python :

```
x = float(0.7)
if x < 0.7 : 
    print("YES")
else : 
    print("NO")
```

Here the output is *NO*

I am confused!  
Maybe I am missing something
Please help me with this problem. 
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have a double, convert it to float to than convert it back to double for the comparison. Loss of precision? Try 0.7f

Comment: Floating point math is not exact.  In C, you're comparing a `float` version of `0.7` to a `double` version of `0.7`.  The `double` version is more accurate, and in this case the `float` version (which is converted to `double` for the comparison) happens to be smaller.  In Python, `float` refers to a double-precision floating point number, so you're comparing a double `0.7` to another double `0.7`, and the result is that they're equal.

Comment: Didn't you ask a question regarding this yesterday? And someone pointed out that `a < 0.7` is a double but `a` is a float? Checked, nope, apparently you and another person had the same exact issue within 24h :)

Comment: ....almost like two assignment dumps.

Comment: theshubhagrwl, why did you code in C with `float` and not `double`?

Comment: The python code is not the same as the C code.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This question was asked in the quiz. I ran it at that time and later searched for the reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
float a = 0.7;
if(a<0.7)
```

The first line above takes the `double` `0.7` and crams it into a `float`, which almost certainly has less precision (so you may lose information).

The second line upgrades the `float a` to a `double` (because you're comparing it with a `double 0.7`, and that's one of the things C does for you) but it's too late at that point, the information is already gone.

You can see this effect with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float a = 0.7;
    float b = 0.7f;
    double c = 0.7;
    printf("a %.50g\nb %.50g\nc %.50g\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

which generates something like:

```
a 0.699999988079071044921875
b 0.699999988079071044921875
c 0.69999999999999995559107901499373838305473327636719
```

*Clearly,* the `double c` variable has about double the precision (which is why they're often referred to as single and double precision) than both:

- the `double 0.7` crammed into the `float a` variable; and
- the `float b` variable that had the `float 0.7` stored into it.

*Neither* of them is exactly `0.7` due to the way floating point numbers work, but the `double` is closer to the desired value, hence not equal to the `float`.

It's like pouring a full four-litre bucket of water into a three-litre bucket and then back again. The litre you lost in the overflow of the smaller bucket doesn't magically re-appear :-)

If you change the type of your `a` to `double`, or use `float` literals like `0.7f`, you'll find things work more as you expect, since there's no loss of precision in that case.

---

The reason why you don't see the same effect in Python is because there's *one* underlying type for these floating point values:

```
>>> x = float(.7)
>>> type(x)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(.7)
<class 'float'>
```

From the Python docs:

> There are three distinct numeric types: integers, floating point numbers, and complex numbers. In addition, Booleans are a subtype of integers. Integers have unlimited precision. ***Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C.***

Hence no loss of precision in that case.

The use of `double` seems to be confirmed by (slightly reformatted):

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.float_info)
sys.float_info(
    max=1.7976931348623157e+308,
    max_exp=1024,
    max_10_exp=308,
    min=2.2250738585072014e-308,
    min_exp=-1021,
    min_10_exp=-307,
    dig=15,
    mant_dig=53,
    epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16,
    radix=2,
    rounds=1
)
```

The exponents and min/max values are identical to those found in [IEEE754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) values.

Answer (score 0):

In `a<0.7` the constant `0.7` is a `double` then `a` which is a `float` is promoted
to `double` before the comparison.
Nothing guarantees that these two constants (as `float` and as `double`) are the same.

As `float` the fractional part of `0.7` is `00111111001100110011001100110011`; as `double` the fractional part of `0.7` is `0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110`.
The value converted from `float` will have its mantissa filled with `0`s when promoted to `double`.
Comparing these two sequences of bits shows that the `double` constant is greater than the `float` constant (the second bit already differs), which
leads to displaying `"Yes"`.

On the other hand, in python, only the `double` representation exists
for floating point numbers; thus there is no difference between what 
is stored in `a` and the constant `0.7` of the comparison, which leads
to displaying `"No"`.